# How can i test Access Control in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Swift Access Control have three type Public,Internal,Private

I can create a project to test if i use Internal or Private

Private can only use in same source file

Internal can only use in same module(or same project)

but how can i test Public?

I don't know how to create two different module to test "Public"

[Swift Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-XID_64)

Comment: Public access is meant for use in a framework.  To test it, you would need to create a framework.

Comment: I know to test Public need to create framework or mudule,but i know the step and how to test

Comment: here's a fairly recent tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9us3uijFFpo.